# Node edit area alterations

Tags: 7, navigation

In my node edit area there are some hyperlinks exposed by the [References Dialog](http://drupal.org/project/references_dialog) module. I need to alter these links by appending some extra information to the url.

**Can anyone tell me what hook to implement which will allow me access to the hyperlinks data and modify them - or even simply altering labels?**

UPDATE:

I code which generates the link I am trying to customize is as follow:

```
function references_dialog_node_reference_add_link($element, $widget_settings, $field, $instance) {
  $add_links = array();
  foreach ($field['settings']['referenceable_types'] as $type => $active) {
    if ($active !== 0) {
      $node_type = node_type_load($type);
      if (node_access('create', $node_type->type)) {
        $add_links[] = array(
          'title' => t('Create @type', array('@type' => $node_type->name)),
          'href' => 'node/add/' . strtr($type, array('_' => '-')),
        );
      }
    }
  }
  return $add_links;
}
```

Here is an image highlighting the links which I am attempting to customize:
[image]

Comment: Which contributed module?  Have you looked at the code for that module?  If you 'grep' for the text that appears in the links, you should be able to find the function that generates them quickly and easily.

Comment: `form_alter` would be your best bet to change it. If you are not comfortable with writing code, look up that function and change it, but make sure that when you update the module you redo the changes.

Comment: Thanks to both you guys for your comments. I updated my question with more details to help clarify what I am attempting to achieve.

Comment: @Stroker: There are 2 problems with your approach. [1]As you alreay mentioned, I need to redo the code when ever I update the module. For this reason, I am looking for a modular solution, which I am very comfortable with               [2]In form_alter, I can't find anything that represents the link. Sure I can access the actual data assigned to the textfields but the link information is not present in $form or $form_state ... I have no idea where to look

Answer (score 0):

There was a patch recently committed to the references dialog module that allows for altering these links.
See http://drupal.org/node/1416922

So if you use the latest development version of the module you can then in a custom module of your own, implement:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_references_dialog_widgets_alter().
 */
function MODULE_NAME_references_dialog_widgets_alter(&$widgets) {
  // Modify $widgets here.
  // $widgets, should be an array of links, including the one you want to alter.
}
```

Comment: Hi Rooby, I appreciate your answer, it's definately a point in the right direction but it just returns the array setup in the references_dialog_references_dialog_widgets function but has no data for the hyperlinks I am attempting to customize. Can you offer anymore help please?